# import cv2 - ImportError: DLL Load Failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Before you slap that downvote button and mark as duplicate, please hear me out as I have allready tried most of the solutions and / or they do not apply to my case.

**Problem**

When importing openCV i am met with the following error:

```
>>>import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "..Python36\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**Possible cause**

As you can see in the pip list below, both dependancies are allready installed.

```
matplotlib 2.1.2
numpy 1.14.1
```

Python version is 3.6.4 and opencv is installed using its wheel as the server I am installing it on is not online. the wheel i used to install was:

```
opencv_python-3.4.3.18-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64
```

Python is not installed using Anaconda so those solutions do not apply.

*However* the server is using Microsoft Visual C++ **2017** Redistributale which means that i cannot install Microsoft Visual C++ **2015** Redistributale.

Could this be the issue? And if so, how would I solve this?

I have also ran DependancyWalker and found the following three .DLL's as reported missing:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
```

However I cannot see that these are actually required?

I have also tried adding opencv_ffmpeg343_64.dll's folder to path.

**pip list**

```
absl-py (0.1.10)
bleach (1.5.0)
brewer2mpl (1.4.1)
certifi (2018.1.18)
chardet (3.0.4)
cognite (0.0.4)
cognite-sdk (0.4.12)
colorama (0.3.9)
cycler (0.10.0)
decorator (4.2.1)
et-xmlfile (1.0.1)
ggplot (0.11.5)
graphviz (0.8.2)
html5lib (0.9999999)
idna (2.6)
influxdb (5.2.0)
ipykernel (4.8.2)
ipython (6.2.1)
ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
jdcal (1.3)
jedi (0.11.1)
jupyter-client (5.2.2)
jupyter-core (4.4.0)
Keras (2.1.4)
Markdown (2.6.11)
matplotlib (2.1.2) <-- Dependancy
mxnet (1.0.0.post4)
numpy (1.14.1) <-- Dependancy
opencv-python (3.4.3.18)
openpyxl (2.5.0)
pandas (0.22.0)
parso (0.1.1)
patsy (0.5.0)
pickleshare (0.7.4)
pip (9.0.3)
prompt-toolkit (1.0.15)
protobuf (3.5.1)
pygal (2.4.0)
Pygments (2.2.0)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
pytz (2018.3)
PyYAML (3.12)
pyzmq (17.0.0)
requests (2.18.4)
scipy (1.0.0)
setuptools (38.5.1)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
six (1.11.0)
statsmodels (0.8.0)
tensorflow (1.5.0)
tensorflow-gpu (1.5.0)
tensorflow-tensorboard (1.5.1)
toposort (1.5)
tornado (4.5.3)
traitlets (4.3.2)
urllib3 (1.22)
wcwidth (0.1.7)
Werkzeug (0.14.1)
wheel (0.30.0)
```

Comment: could it be that you have also python 2.x and it is installed to that one and not the python 3.6? or that by whatever reason you have more than one python installed? How did you install it? I mean, did you just write `pip install opencv_python-3.4.3.18-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` ? or something different? maybe you can write the absolute path to pip to make sure you install it to the correct python

Comment: I am 100% sure that there is only one python version installed.

I also provided the entire path to the wheel when installing using pip

Comment: can you try with `python -m pip install opencv_python-3.4.3.18-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64` and try agin to import?

Comment: Done. (uninstalled first offcourse) same result, and same files site-packages/cv2 folder

Comment: Could it be some other DLL's that needs to be added to the path variable?

Comment: I think it may really require the 2015c++ redist... You may try to compile the library from sources and create the python that may use 2017 c++.... or find a wheel that may do it

Comment: as shown here? ( Building OpenCV from source ) 
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

Comment: yes, exactly like that

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a shot, my knowledge about DLL's and things like this is quite limited though.

BTW. Do you know of any alternatives that might work for me? I'm only using cv2.ConnectedComponents

Comment: scikit-image: https://www.scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/auto_examples/plot_labels.html . Should do perfect for this... here is the how to install it: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot as well =)